# With only one console writeline, how can I give multiple console writelines?

Tags: c#, console.writeline

There are multiple Console.WriteLine() arguments between some values, but I don't want to give them all separately by copypaste, is there any way I can specify the number of WriteLine arguments with just one argument and it'll be done .

here is some example

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 };// giving values
        int[] arr2 = { 34444, 111 };
        loop();//calling the method
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        printArray(arr1);//passing arrays
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        printArray(arr2);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        minArray(arr1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        minArray(arr2);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        maxArray(arr1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        maxArray(arr2);
```

Comment: On the face of it, no, but maybe you could provide some actual code to illustrate what you're talking about.

Comment: Please provide some code to illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: i have give some example, now

Comment: Why not using loops?

Comment: public static void WriteLines(int count), use a for-loop.

Comment: You can call one Console.WriteLine with as much  `\n` as you need.

Comment: @Cid Since I have many values to pass one after another, I have to give specific write lines between the values, so I don't think creating one forloop with a defined number of lines is a good idea for me. If you can help me figure out how to change the values of the for loop, please let me know.

Comment: @HansPassant can u show it in detail please , it looks like it will solve the issue

Comment: You can use `Console.Write(new String(Environment.NewLine, NumberOfDesiredNewLines));` (Note the usage of `Write` instead of `WriteLine`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to create a function that prints '\n' (symbol of new line) as many times as you need. `new String` can help us with repetition of '\n'.
So the function might look like this:

```
static void PrintNewLine(int n)
{
    string newLines = new String('\n',n-1);
    Console.WriteLine(newLines);
}
```

You might notice `n-1` inside the function.
We added it just because WriteLine puts one `\n` into console itself.

Here is an example of usage:

```
static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    PrintNewLine(5);
    Console.WriteLine("Another Hello");
}
```

It will print `Hello` followed by 5 blank lines followed by `Another Hello`

Comment: ('\n',n-1);  , can u explain this part , why n-1 , and what is \n

Comment: We put `n-1` inside the function because `WriteLine` puts one `\n` into console itself

Comment: @Player91 just commented it :D

Comment: Better use `Environment.NewLine` instead or "\n" for platform-independence

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 6)));
Console.WriteLine("World");
```

This will print six empty lines between Hello and World.